# Your binary is not optimized for iPhone 5 - (ERROR ITMS-90096)

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7

I get this error when trying to archive my application:

[image]

I don't understand, because I am not using LaunchImage in my application.

My settings looks like this:
[image]

Any suggestions on what I can do here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because your Deployment Target is set to iOS 7.0.

A Launch Screen File is only supported for iOS 8.0 and later.

In order to support iOS 7 you must provide launch images. You can keep the Launch Screen file too but it will only be used on devices running iOS 8.0 and later.

So setup the asset catalog for the Launch Images Source and add the needed set of launch images for iOS 7.

Of course your other option is to drop support for iOS 7 then your use of the Launch Screen File will be sufficient.

Comment: Can i just add a 1 black image into one of the boxes in the LaunchScreen image.assets?

Comment: It depends on what devices you wish to support with iOS 7. At a minimum you need the "Retina 4" launch image. It should be a proper launch image though. You may not be rejected for using a black image but your users will hate seeing that.

Comment: What happens if i set "Deployment Target" iOS 8.0, and someone with IOS 7.0 wanna use my app?

Comment: If your Deployment Target is set to iOS 8.0 then no one with iOS 7 will be able to install your app. If this is an update, iOS 7 users will be stuck with the last version that supported iOS 7.

Comment: I dont mind using that black image.. How do i do it?

Comment: Click on that `Use Asset Catalog` button next to Launch Images Source. Then populate the place holders for the Launch Images asset as needed. You will first need to create images of the proper size. Use your favorite paint program for that or take screenshots using the simulators.

Comment: I only need 1 image, right? In order to success upload to archive?

Comment: You need all of the images for the devices your app will run under on iOS 7. Do it right for your users. Don't take the lazy way out just to rush the app to the App Store.

Comment: Made it work now, thanks! Don't worry, no rushy way :)